# literature for developing for android with adobe AIR

Tags: android, air, air-android

Please, recommend me some good literature for developing applications for Android OS with Adobe AIR. I am beginer in this. Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a book about developing android application with Adobe Air : [Adobe Air](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449394825)

Answer (score 1):

here are some informations how to develope air applications: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/documentation.html.

Answer (score 1):

Main resources for all Air packaging inquiries: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/packaging-air-apps.html